# Will my site disappear if I stop paying for "Basic Managed WordPress" (Wordpress Managment), but continue paying my GoDaddy hosting subscription?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, godaddy

I have a site that I made using WordPress, and hosted with GoDaddy a couple years ago. It's mostly a blog/journal of a long trip I took, which is interesting for me and my family, but mostly useless to the world. I want to keep it on the web for my own reference, but I don't have any intention to further add to it or develop it.

Because I don't want to change or develop it any more, can I continue to pay hosting costs (via GoDaddy), but can I STOP paying the "Basic Managed WordPress Websites" annual charge ($120)?

If I do this, will my site disappear or break?

Comment: I had to edit your question to make it meet this site's requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The site will break. It's being hosted by WordPress, and I'm only paying GoDaddy for the domain.

It's possible to take a copy of my site and move it to a new hosting platform, although it seems like Basic WordPress is one of the cheapest. And if I move away from GoDaddy, it seems like I'll lose the domain.

EDIT:

But...!

I was able to download my site with HTTrack and then create a github repo that can include a static site. Just google " "host static site on github" . This was perfect for me, because I just want an archive of all my travels. I put a lot of work into that blog for my family, and it'd be a shame to lose it. Now I'll just pay for the domain, and redirect it, saving me the $120 for WordPress hosting.

This was exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!